# If a question is closed due to no objective victory criterion, and has many answers already, should duplicates of it be allowed?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, winning-criteria

I recently came across [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1798/62131), which is (rightfully) closed as having no victory condition. Most of the existing answers don't aim for any particular goal other than answering the question, so reopening the question as [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) would be a bad idea.

However, it's a question that's fairly obvious to ask *with* a victory condition. Someone tried a while back, asking [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/19594/62131) [popularity-contest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/popularity-contest). It was almost immediately closed as a duplicate. As such, there's currently nowhere you can go to post answers to the question in question (and it's a fairly obvious question, given how many variants on it have been posted).

My question here is partially about those posts, but mostly about the general case. If a question receives answers, and is rightfully closed for not having an objective victory criterion, should we allow the question to be reposted, specifying a victory criterion, without closing the reposts as duplicates?

Comment: In this specific case, it's also important to note that the old challenge was on-topic when it was posted, and closed as off-topic more than a year after the supposed dupe was posted/closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a challenge is closed as off-topic, it shouldn't be used as a dupe target. Thus, making an on-topic version of the challenge is perfectly acceptable.

As [ETHproductions pointed out](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11596/if-a-question-is-closed-due-to-no-objective-victory-criterion-and-has-many-answ#comment38547_11596):

> In this specific case, it's also important to note that the old challenge was on-topic when it was posted, and closed as off-topic more than a year after the supposed dupe was posted/closed.

When the second challenge was posted, the original hadn't been closed as off-topic yet, so it was a valid dupe target. Now that it has been closed, feel free to post a rewrite of it with an objective winning criteria, so long as it meets our current standards (which are much higher than when the original challenge was posted).